# Django Rest Framework With Djoser Jwt

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, djoser

I was looking into have more secure login and logout using JWT authentication and authorization .But in Djoser ,it has 3 endpoints /jwt/create/,/jwt/refresh/,/jwt/verify/.

Here I want user login with jwt token and get verified token simultaneously and when logout refresh comes in to get access token.How could I do this?

Comment: I don't understand what you want. "Logout" works by simply discarding any token you have. What do you want with a new refresh token at logout…?!

Comment: when logout access token discarded ,then using refresh token we get access token again right?so where exactly refresh token come from and how do I use it?